# For Windows systems, will ".bat" or ".cmd" extension make any difference for my script?

Tags: windows, command-line, shell-script, batch-file

Assuming that my shell script is entirely based on DOS commands(dir, cd, etc and not VBS or PowerShell commands), using .cmd or .bat extension for it's name will change something? I mean, it will be executed as the same way and with the same interpreter if using .cmd or .bat extension?

Comment: Note that *neither* extension means any kind of DOS is being used. On Windows NT systems, both extensions are handled by the same `cmd.exe` interpreter, which is a native Windows program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well written answer from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd).

So, no it doesn't affect your commands. The handling of the ERRORLEVEL is just different. In cmd, the ERRORLEVEL will be set regardless if there is an error or not.

Bat only does, if there is an error.

> From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file):
>
> New Quote from Wikipedia
>
> > The only known difference between .cmd
> >     and .bat file execution is that in a
> >     .cmd file the ERRORLEVEL variable
> >     changes even on a successful command
> >     that is affected by Command Extensions
> >     (when Command Extensions are enabled),
> >     whereas in .bat files the ERRORLEVEL
> >     variable changes only upon errors.
>
> The source for the Wikipedia quote above is actually based on [this
>   news group
>   posting](https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win2000.cmdprompt.admin/msg/ad9066638815812c).
>
> > The differences between .CMD and .BAT as far as CMD.EXE is concerned
> >     are:  With extensions enabled, PATH/APPEND/PROMPT/SET/ASSOC in .CMD 
> >     files will set ERRORLEVEL regardless of error. .BAT sets ERRORLEVEL 
> >     only on errors.
>
> Note only is it a little more restrictive concerning the differences,
>   than the Wikipedia text, but is also worth being explicitly mentioned,
>   given the fact [Mark
>   Zbikowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zbikowski) himself -
>   which gives a huge credibility bonus IMHO.